# Can't upgrade solution after renaming feature

Tags: sharepoint, deployment

I am currently working on a deployment solution for an Sharepoint 2013 project using SPSD.

As with most projects, we kept different versions for different stages of the project. On our early versions, we had named a feature "Definitions and WebParts" but then we decided to do away with the WebParts so we renamed the feature "Definitions".

Now, I have the problem that if I just upgrade the solution, I get an error `"The solution cannot be deployed.  The feature '' uses the directory '' in the solution. However, it is currently installed in the farm to the directory ''. Uninstall the existing feature before you install a new version of the solution."`

So I disable and uninstall it prior to the feature being upgraded. Although I don't get the previous error anymore, I now get a new one: `"The solution file located at "" does not appear to be a valid upgrade for solution "".The two solutions must have the same resource types (global or Web-application scoped)."`

Does anybody know what this error means or how I should be doing the upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I came across this blog and probably the explanation is relevant in your case
http://snahta.blogspot.com.au/2009/09/solution-file-located-at-xxxxwsp-does.html

Reason:
This can be due to change in feature scope or addition of a new feature in the solution package from its previous version.

SharePoint is complaining by saying that the solution was either deployed Globally last time and this time you are trying to deploy it to a specific Url or the other way around.

Solution:
I will suggest to better retract/delete the old solution and add/deploy the new one.

But just in case you have issues with this approach, I will suggest to compare the features in the solution package and move it to another solution package.

Comment: we only had the old version deployed to our company server so we ended up just deleting everything by power shell. I will just be more careful before renaming a feature again from now on :)